# How can a HTML file be rendered within WebSVN?

Tags: html, repository, raw

We've just switched over to using WebSVN and I want to be able to link users of my code to rendered HTML documentation files in the repositories.

So, I don't want users to have to check out the code first and then to open the HTML documentation file; I want to be able to link them directly to a rendering of the HTML view that is available via WebSVN. I should mention that our WebSVN is protected too.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set this SVN property on the HTML files in question:

`svn:mime-type text/html`

This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100121/how-do-i-serve-html-thru-svn-can-svn-act-as-a-web-server.